# storing values from an array into another array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array as follows:

```
var localproducts = [packageId, categoryId, dataId];
```

I want to go through this array with the each function and store all dataIds into another new array of all items that have a certain packageID i.e if pacakgeId is 3 than I want to store the dataId into a new array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you have an array like that, there's only one `dataId` in it. Do you actually have an array like this? `var localproducts = [[packageId, categoryId, dataId], ...];`

Comment: it's supposed to be an object array I think it's called, maybe shouldn-t be using commas, i.e. want a list of packageIds, categoryIDs and dataIds.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you have an object array, so you need to keep the objects with property `packageId` equal to 3. You should have a look at [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

The code would basically look like this:

```
function filter($var) {
  return $var->packageId == 3;
}

$filtered_values = array_filter($localProducts, filter);
```

You can do the same for an array or arrays, just change the filter function like this:

```
function filter($var) {
  return $var['packageId'] == 3;
}
```

Now, if you want to create a new array with only the values `dataId` should be done with a simple `foreach`.

```
var $dataIds = array();

foreach($localProducts as $prod) {
  if($prod->packageId == 3) {
    $dataIds[] = $prod->dataId;
  }
}
```

Comment: but how does that return all the dataids of items with packageIds of 3?

Comment: @user1937021 It returns the complete objects, you can then get the `dataId` you want, or any other information.

Comment: sorry but how can I save all the dataids of the result of that in a variable? Thanks